# Stanford Core NLP train tagger using Java API

Tags: stanford-nlp

Does anyone know if it's possible to train a Stanford tagger using the Java API? I'm only finding examples of people doing it through the command line. That should imply that there exists an API method somewhere, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all of your training properties in a `.properties` file and then call `MaxentTagger.main("-props", "/path/to/training.properties")`.  I don't see any easier way to do this in the Java API.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I came up with is to use MaxentTagger.main(...) and pass it a bunch of arguments that have been formatted command line style.